# Issue with a basic password program

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a password checker but an error occurs. It wants me to change an int to String but I want the password to be the number 5, so it has to be an int?

```
public class Kode {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, please write the password");
        int num1 = scanner.nextLine();
        if (num1 == 5) {
            System.out.println("Welcome");
        }
        else  {
            System.out.println("Password incorrect");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A password is a string and not a number.

Comment: Does that compile? You're getting `scanner.nextLine()` which returns a **String** and you want an int -- so use a different method, say... `scanner.nextInt()`??

Comment: Sorry mate, as I said I'm still new to all this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `nextLine()` method will return a String, so this won't even compile is my guess. You need to change the type of `num1` to a `String`. Then compare it to the password you want with `num1.equals("5");`. You should also rename it from `num1` to something more descriptive, as it's not explicitly a number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this... It will parse the String to the wanted int

```
int num1=Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Comment: Add 4 whitespaces left of your code to enable syntax highlight. [(Help page about formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Try `scanner.nextInt()` instead of `scanner.nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

The nextLine() method returns a String and num1 is of type int so it won't compile.
You can change the String to an int by using Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()).
This throws an exception if the String is not a number.
However, you seem to want the password to be 5 but not necessarily a number. So make num1 a String, and call it userInput or something more descriptive.